# Is there a way to reflect a sphere so that it behaves as a skybox in A-frame? (A-frame docs suggestion not working)

Tags: scale, aframe, skybox

I followed the docs exactly as described (refer

> https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/scale.html)

in a super basic WebVR scene on Glitch and it seems the code related to reflecting a sphere along the Z-axis won't work. It seems to be fairly straightforward, so I can't imagine why there should be any trouble. Am I doing something stupid or is it really not working? I know I could use a-sky but I want more control over position, rotation, etc (it needs to be an element in the world).

- A-Frame Version: 1.0.4
- Platform / Device: Windows ASUS Rog Zephyrus Laptop, Desktop browser (tested on Firefox and Edge)
- Reproducible Code Snippet or URL: https://east-stock.glitch.me/. Ideally, you shouldn't be able to see the sphere from "outside" it, as in this scene, and the red should appear once you navigate "inside" the sphere.

Just so you have it, this is what I put in my scene:

```
  <a-entity
    geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 4"
    material="color: red"
    scale="1 1 -1"
    position="0 0 -5"
  ></a-entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some properties to the material of the sphere to get it to work.

```
<a-entity
    geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 4"
    material="color: red; side: back; shader: flat; "
    scale="1 1 1"
    position="0 0 -5"
></a-entity>
```

You only want to show the 'back' of the faces of the sphere, that's what the `side:back` does. You probably don't want the sphere to reflect the light, therefore in this case I would add the `shader:flat` parameter so it is rendered flat.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work, nearly. In my tests side:back and side:double seem to be doing the same thing (both render the sphere whether inside or outside).

Comment: 'double' shows both the in and outside of the sphere. So if you are inside side the sphere, you would have the same effect.

Comment: Yes, but side:back seems to do the same thing for me, hence the confusion. The sphere is still visible from the outside using the side:back setting. 

EDIT: I just realized this is probably the part of the sphere furthest from you that is actually being rendered and so still visible. The sphere wouldn't become invisible using side:back